# DialogFragment background color varies on different platforms

Tags: android

I'm implementing custom DialogFragment and having problems with font color.

Here is problematic TextView view code:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/message"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/secondary_text_light"
        android:text="@string/loading_message" />
```

And this is how the DialogFragment is created.

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
    ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_undetermined_progress, null);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);   
    messageView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
    messageView.setText(message);

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(title).setView(view);

    return builder.create(); 
}
```

If Android supports holo it's all fine because the dialog is white, and TextView is visible. But on several 2.3 platforms, which is also dependant on manufacturer layer, the DialogFragment can be dark, and the TextView color is nearly invisible.

Is there any android color I could use to get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Check out [`HoloEverywhere`](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere). It is a library that brings a backport of the `Holo` theme to 2.x devices to solve this very problem. I have implemented it with few issues.

If that is too much work, and you are really only looking to color the background of this one view check out [these options](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/colors.xml), which show the values of the base Android `Holo` colors. You could just copy over whatever values you wanted.

These seem most useful to you:

```
<color name="background_holo_dark">#ff000000</color>
<color name="background_holo_light">#fff3f3f3</color>
```